# Simple gmail script. If value can be found in inbox then add a label

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, google-drive-api

Each of a 1000 values shall be searched in the inbox.

How would you go for that?

(*...and all resulting conversations marked with a label.*

*the list of course is available in every way, Google spreadsheet, txt,...*

*i tried to simply tie all values together like 1|2|3|...|1000 
to one search, but of course Google doesn’t allow such a long search-term...*)

thanks

edit: as i know too little about gmail scripts yet, 
i tried to manually solved it (despite its a recurring task) and found that a search term can have about 1500 chars or 90 values before it results in errors. A "#" will break it and only search for the first half or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do several searches, and make an algorithm that can process by chunks of search terms using timers (1 minute timers for example.).
If a search returns many items it gets more complex as you will need to save the search somewhere like scriptdb and also process those by chunks.

Comment: each search only has 0 to 50 results,
for a script i guess it wouldnt be too much to searchh term one by one in a loop and just wait a second between each if there is a limit?